# Wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

I'm finishing my PhD thesis and I encounter my last problem (I hope) while trying to embody my picture in the biography section. I understand that wrapfigure can't be used in any type of list environment, however it appears that in template I'm using \appendix changes this environment. This is how main document looks:

```
\documentclass{dissertation}

\usepackage{xspace}

\begin{document}

\title[Title]{Subtitle} \author{Please}{Help}

\frontmatter

\include{title/title}

\include{summary/summary}

\tableofcontents  
\listoffigures 
\listoftables

%% Use Arabic numerals for the page numbers of the chapters. 
\mainmatter

%% Turn on thumb indices. 
\thumbtrue

\include{chapter-1/chapter-1} 
\include{chapter-2/chapter-2} 
\include{chapter-5/chapter-5} 
\include{chapter-3/chapter-3} 
\include{chapter-4/chapter-4} 
\include{chapter-6/chapter-6} 
\include{conclusion/conclusion}


%% Use letters for the chapter numbers of the appendices. 
\appendix 
\include{appendix/appendix-a} 
\include{appendix/appendix-b}

\references{refchapt2}

%% Turn off thumb indices for unnumbered chapters. 

\thumbfalse

\include{acks/acks} 
\include{cv/cv}

\include{publications/publications}

\end{document}
```

There is no problem in using wrapfigure in chapter part, before \appendix, however after that it gives errors:

> Wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment

and

> Stationary wrapfigure forced to float

and just includes picture bellow the text. Any way to work around this?

Comment: For us to help you, we need a MWE we can copy and run.  Throw out everything you can and still reproduce the problem.  Also, wrapfig is not the only way to handle images, especially for single paragraphs and no caption.

Comment: Can you recommend some other ways? It's just simply adding picture with no captions and two paragraphs.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513895/wrap-text-around-tikzpicture-environment and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281450/wrap-text-around-a-figure-inside-a-floating-box/281481?r=SearchResults&s=5|12.8972#281481 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451489/how-to-align-an-image-right-next-to-text for example.

Comment: Thanks, using minipage can do the job. Only problem left is that chapter title is on empty page while minipage box is position in the middle of next page. Is there a way to position minibox?

Comment: Probably.  As stated, earlier, a Minimal Working Example would help.

Comment: Thanks for keep trying to help me. I uploaded the example on Dropbox, try to download it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1i11t1hvqz47x5g/example.zip?dl=0

Comment: It's not entire dissertation of course. It's just a template I used and I recreated the problem I have in CV section of it (pages 13-14). I think you need all the files from the template in order to see the problem. As I said before there is no problem in using Wrapfigure in part with main chapter, problem occurs when I want to use it after appendix, at the end of thesis, where biography section should be.